# Why is memcache/redis needed when having an "onOneServer" schedule?

Tags: laravel, scheduler

When faced with an architecture that involves several webservers running the same laravel application, the problem of availability arises.

When two servers are involved, only one of them should run a scheduled job. In that scenario, you would obviously use the `onOneServer` attribute.

For details, see [the laravel documentation on that matter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server).

Now here's the actual question: the documentation says

> {note} To utilize this feature, your application must be using the memcached or redis cache driver as your application's default cache driver. In addition, all servers must be communicating with the same central cache server.

I just don't get why this should not be possible using the database backend. I'd appreciate any hint you can provide.

Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[When Taylor introduced](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/laravel-5-6-preview-single-server-scheduling-54df8e0e139b) the `onOneServer()` feature, he explained it in this way:

> Note: When using this feature, you will need to use the Redis or Memcached cache drivers. **These drivers provide the atomicity needed to secure the locks that power this feature.**

You can read more about [distributed locking in redis](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-2-distributed-locking/). I am aware that some of the database drivers, such as *MySQL* also provides lock-features, so I would assume this feature would potentially also work on those. However, as of right now, they aren't implemented.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik! Since, let's say as an example, three frontends running laravel use the same database backend anyway, I would assume that the database would be a perfect place to implement some locking - may it be implemented logically or simply by using transactions or some actual row locking mechanism. But OK, you're saying that it simply isn't implemented in Laravel and there is no actual technical argument that would prevent somebody from implementing this in the laravel database driver / caching layer (as this seems to be the place where "schedules" are implemented), right?

Comment: Taylor Otwell also [chimed in](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1127352181017812992).

Comment: Yes, that sums it up pretty well. I'm not sure what you are referring to with the schedules sentence though.

Comment: The sentence was referring to me not being sure why those schedules are intertwined with the caching layer. But that questions is out of scope here.

Meanwhile, also the developer of the onOneServer-feature [got back to me](https://twitter.com/laurenceioannou/status/1127786038078976001).

Comment: I partially disagree with the above statement on Mysql. For this to work @Fredrik, you need to be certain that each of your Laravel instances connect to one and only one DB, if you have multiple DB's as well, the theory above fails to prove it's concept because the resources do not have the shared point of interest. Wanted to bring the a little bit of light into that one. Thanks.